# returning object to caller of a service

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I'm using Angular 7 and Angular Material to display a dialog box.  I've written a service (modal.service) to show the dialog, but I'd like to pass the dialogReference from MatDialog.open back to the calling component, so it can do any post-processing when the dialog closes.

Here's my modal.service:

```
import { ReviewModalComponent } from './../components/review-modal/review-modal.component';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

  dialogRef : any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  showReviewModal(id, mode){
    this.dataService.getReview(id).subscribe(
      (review:any) => {
        this._openReviewModal(id, mode, review);
      }
    );
  }

  _openReviewModal(id, mode, review){
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ReviewModalComponent, {width: '500px', data: { id: id, mode: mode, review: review } })
    .afterClosed().subscribe(result => {alert('closed')});
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I pass this.dialogRef back to my calling component, so I can subscribe to .afterClosed there?

Here's my calling component (or part of it, anyway):

```
openReviewDialog(id): void {
    this.modalService.showReviewModal(id, 'edit');//.subscribe(x=>alert(x));
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So the sole purpose is to get the data into the calling component or why do you want to have the reference there?

Comment: Just to know when the modal closes, so I I can update the calling component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use **[a subject to communicate](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)**. Depending on the case, you could just return `dialogRef` to the calling component and subscribe there. Since you are calling another function in the service, we use `switchMap` to chain the requests:

```ts
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ....

showReviewModal(id, mode){
  return this.dataService.getReview(id).pipe(
    switchMap((review:any) => this._openReviewModal(id, mode, review))
  );
}

_openReviewModal(id, mode, review){
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(...)

  return dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('maybe service needs to do stuff also?'))
  );
}
```

and the calling component then subscribes:

```ts
openReviewDialog(id): void {
   this.modalService.showReviewModal(id, 'edit').subscribe(x => alert(x));
}
```

If this solution isn't suitable for you regarding reusability, I would suggest a subject like the link I provided.

**[DEMO of the above code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff4695-8kdy4m?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)**

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to put that demo together.  The problem, though, is I'm calling _openReviewModal from within a 'subscribe' of the showReviewModal method.  Is there a way to do what you suggest given this particular architecture?

Comment: Oh gosh, I didn't see that one at all. I just with my tired eyes looked that `openReviewDialog` calls `_openReviewModal`. Now I see that it doesn't :D I'm going to bed now, but if you haven't received any other help by when I wake up, I'll take another look!

Comment: @WOPR, I updated my answer, now it should do what you want :)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much!  I will try it out at work on Monday

Comment: So this code works perfectly!  But, could you explain how the .afterClosed observable makes it way back to the caller of this service?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you! We are using switchMap in the `showReviewModal` to return `_openReviewModal` result to the original subscriber. switchMap is very useful for flattening in chaining (http or any observable) requests.